# how to find restaurant list near current location using mapkit in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I want to know how to find nearest restaurant using mapkit in iphone sdk?
I want to display current location of user and then want to display restaurant near tht location...

if neone have idea please help me in this

Thanks 
nir

Answer (score 0):

This should help

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/

Should help you get started.  There is a series of map tutorials.