# Is it possible for search for nearby restaurants and bars via API for iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find restaurant list near current location using mapkit in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042807/how-to-find-restaurant-list-near-current-location-using-mapkit-in-iphone)
>   [How to find out the near by restaurants using current location details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289170/how-to-find-out-the-near-by-restaurants-using-current-location-details)

I would like to know if it is possible to search nearby restaurants via ANY API for iPhone SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have google Places API and SimpleGeo API

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

https://simplegeo.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the Yelp API that will help you

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at your favorite search engine service and see if it exposes some API:

http://www.tripadvisor.com/help/what_is_an_api  TripAdvisor
http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/places/  Google Places
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api Yelp

And so on..