# Showing nearby restaurants in MKMap View

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

In my iphone app,I have to show near by restaurants in Map View,Currently I am using Google map url in a web view.

But how can I show nearby restaurants with in 5000 meters of current location with native MKMap view(I found out my current location-lat&long)

I would like to learn how to implement as in the below screen shot(by clicking the annotations going to its detail too)

Any helps ?? thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Googling on Google Place API

Comment: no..I am not talking about google place API,that I am able to show it on a WEBView,I wish to implement it on iOS maps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387154/is-it-possible-for-search-for-nearby-restaurants-and-bars-via-api-for-iphone-sdk

Comment: this is hugely out of date.  Simply use MKMapKit, which is totally built-in to iOS these days. it's only a couple lines of code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In iOS 6.1, you can use [`MKLocalSearch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html), part of the standard iOS MapKit.framework:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";
request.region = mapView.region;

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

    [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];

        annotation.title = item.name;
        annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        annotation.phone = item.phoneNumber;

        [annotations addObject:annotation];
    }];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
}];
```

My custom annotation is just a `MKPlacemark` plus a title and subtitle:

```
@interface CustomAnnotation : MKPlacemark

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;

@end
```

If you want to see the disclosure indicator on your callout (so you can transition to another controller to view the details, you can:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
        return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                       reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotationView"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;
}
```

If you want to open your other view when the user clicks on the callout accessory:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if (![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
        return;
    CustomAnnotation *annotation = (CustomAnnotation *)view.annotation;

    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef) annotation.title, NULL);

    if (annotation.phone)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) annotation.phone, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }

    ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) annotation.addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, NULL);
    ABUnknownPersonViewController *personView = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];

    personView.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
    personView.displayedPerson = person;
    personView.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personView animated:YES];

    CFRelease(address);
    CFRelease(person);
}

- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownPersonView didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

}
```

For more information (e.g. customizing the annotation views, determining device location, etc.), refer to the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

See https://github.com/robertmryan/MKMapView-custom-annotations for a simple example.

Comment: Thanks it worked...:) 
I can pass the title to the detail page as below,how to pass the subtitle ?


Please see this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954240/how-to-pass-subtitle-of-annotation-in-mkmapview

Comment: @NithinMK You'd pass it in the same way you'd pass the title. Personally, I think it's just easier to pass the `annotation` itself, that way the detail page can just access all of the properties of the annotation. If you're still having problems, post a new question with your code to create the annotation as well as your code to launch the details page and we can help you further. Feel free to add a link to the new question here so that I can see it when you post it.

Answer (score 0):

First refer this Google API Link https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search and then get id and add this in parameter of **googleId** and just set **radious** parameter with 5000 value and for **types** set value restaurant..

See my bellow example..

```
NSString *str=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=5000&types=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",currentLocation.latitude,currentLocation.longitude,@"restaurant",@"AIzaSyB7YTFTYyk9eb8ULNGxoy06-b_0DUOqdrY"];
NSLog(@"\n\n URL %@",str);
NSURL *strurl=[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@"%7C"]];
//    NSURL *strurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB7YTFTYyk9eb8ULNGxoy06-b_0DUOqdrY"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:strurl];  
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

and implement these whole record on `MKMapView` like bellow...

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"\n\n>>>>......Response String >>> %@",responseString);

    if(responseString)
    {
        SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];

        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"\n\n.......This is Mutable Array");
        }
        else 
        {
            if ([[result objectForKey:@"results"] count]>0) 
            {
                NSLog(@">>>>>>>> dict keys :%d \nFull Address : %@\n LatLong : %@ \n total result : %d", [[result objectForKey:@"results"] count],[[result objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"vicinity"],[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"],[[result objectForKey:@"results"]count]);


                for (int i=0; i<[[result objectForKey:@"results"] count]; i++)     
                {
                    ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    ann.title = [[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
                    ann.subtitle = [[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"vicinity"];   

                    ann.annReferance=[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"reference"];

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
                    location.latitude = [[[[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
                    location.longitude = [[[[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
                    ann.coordinate=location;
                    ann.annLocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude];

                    //                    NSLog(@"\n\n rating %@",ann.annrating);
                    if ([[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i] allKeys] containsObject:@"rating"]) 
                    {
                        // contains key
                        ann.annrating=[[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"rating"]stringValue];
                        NSLog(@"\n\n rating %@",ann.annrating);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ann.annrating=@"";
                    }
                    ann.annaddress=[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"vicinity"];
                    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is code which i use in my application, just do some changes with your requirement and you will get output..

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: you most wel-come :) just create MyAnnotation class or something which you want to display with other parameters..

Comment: but...What is ASIFormDataRequest??

Comment: oh i use ASIHTTPRequest for send request and get data from api .. just add ASIHTTPRequest and add .h file in your current class's .m file , its a class which used for send request to server and get data back...